# How do we mock a method A of class z which is called inside a private method B of Class C and call private method B from Junit using powermock?

Tags: java, junit, powermock

How do we mock a call to method A of class z which is inside a private method B of Class C and call private method B from Junit using powermock ?

Call to method A is inside private method B has to be mocked since its an external call .

```
Class A
{
Private method B(String r, String y)
a= z.method A(external URL)
}
```

Now when we call B using WhiteBox.invoke (A,"B","x","y") in the Junit I should be able to mock method A also since its external call .

```
Sample code is shown below :
public class StudentScoreUpdates {
    public IDatabase databaseImpl;

    public StudentScoreUpdates(IDatabase databaseImpl) {
        this.databaseImpl = databaseImpl;
    }

    private void calculateSumAndStore(String studentId, int[] scores) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int score : scores) {
            total = total + score;
        }
// write total to DB, this is external HTTP call which needs to be mocked
        databaseImpl.updateScores(studentId, total);
    }
}
So when I call the private method in Junit testing I should be able to mock databaseImpl.updateScores(studentId, total)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the class structure? Are you unable to create a Mock for Class C and then mock the behaviour of method A?

Comment: so the Class A structure is very simple its Public java class with a private method and the method a is belong to another Class Z from where we make this external call